# How to customize container name in docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  rocketchat:
    image: foo/foo:3.9.1
    container_name: $FOO_CONTAINER_NAME


.env file contains
    FOO_CONTAINER_NAME=foo_container
```

I want the container name to reflect lifecycle environment (say dev, staging, prod), how to customize this. I tried the following, but it didn't help

```
container_name: $FOO_CONTAINER_NAME_$ENV
container_name: $FOO_CONTAINER_NAME_{$ENV}"
```

ENV is declared in .env file as dev, staging ..

Answer (score 1):

`docker-compose.yaml` content:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  rocketchat:
    image: foo/foo:3.9.1
    container_name: ${FOO_CONTAINER_NAME}_${ENV}
```

`.env` content:

```
FOO_CONTAINER_NAME=foo_container
ENV=staging
```

running `docker-compose config` output:

```
services:
  rocketchat:
    container_name: foo_container_staging
    image: foo/foo:3.9.1
version: '3.8'
```

Comment: WARNING: The FOO_CONTAINER_NAME_ variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. I get the following error instead, this is what I have already and couldn't get it to work

Comment: can you share your `.env` file?